# Sequence of Functions and Integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This is one of my questions in the study guide: Suppose a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ defined on the interval $[a,b]$ converges uniformly to a function limit $f$ on the closed interval $[a,b]$. Let $P$ be any partition of $[a,b]$. Prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that: 
$$ | U(f,P) - U(f_n,P)| < \epsilon  \text{ whenever $n > N$ }$$

I first show that the function limit $f$ is bounded which is the necessary condition for Rienmann integrabiblity. But is it necessary for the hypothesis to have for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $f_n$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. I would be happy if there is any approach to this question.

Answer (score 3):

The question involves only a fixed partition so it has nothing to do with integrability. Show that $|\sup_I f-\sup_I f_n| <\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large for each subinterval of the partition. This implies the stated inequality for the upper sums.

Comment: $P$ is any partition of $[a,b]$. You mean a fixed partition is $P= [a=x_0 < x_1 <...<x_n = b]$

Comment: Yes, that is what the question says.